# A number defined on a class logged as NaN at the class's function

Tags: nan, mousewheel, class-variables

I defined a variable when creating a class;

```
this.iscale = 1 ;
```

And when i try to console log the variable in class' function that process the mousewheel event ; it is reported NaN. 
I console log same variable in another function of same class . It was logged 1 as it should be.

What is wrong here ...?

EDITED : Simple layout is here ..When i shorten the code i might have been forgotten some variables so that is not the point really ..Cause class works fine. But fails on mousewheel function. :

```
class contentImage {

        constructor(source, container) {
            this.img = new Image();
            this.src = source;
            this.iscale = 1;
            this.load();
        }
        load() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var self = this;
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                self.imgdat = e.target.result;
                self.initZoom();
                self.prepare();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.src);
        }
        prepare() {
            //console.log("prepare");
            var self = this;
            this.img.onload = function() {
                self.initZoom();
                self.draw();
            };
            this.img.src = this.imgdat;   
        }
        draw() {
             console.log("SCALE : "+this.iscale);
        // I log this.iscale here. And it is 1 ::

        }

        zoomImage(event) {
            var rolled;
            if ('wheelDelta' in event) {
                rolled = event.wheelDelta;
            } else { // Firefox
              rolled = -40 * event.detail;
            }
            this.iscale+=(rolled/Math.abs(rolled))/10;
            console.log(this.iscale);
        }
        initZoom() {
         // this.con is container canvas
            if (this.con.addEventListener) { 
                this.con.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.zoomImage, true);

                this.con.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.zoomImage, true);
            } else {
                if (this.con.attachEvent) { // IE before version 9
                    this.con.attachEvent("onmousewheel", this.zoomImage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a bit more of your code, I can't see anything wrong with what you've got so far

Comment: You aren't checking that rolled is not zero.

Comment: I will Lissy preparing..

Comment: I logged also the rolled İt is logged either 120 or -120; Since that was fired in mousewheel event ..It can not be 0 i guess or ?

Comment: @vinegarbin `rolled` looks fine to me? That shouldn't cause an issue with accessing `this.iscale` anyway ?

Comment: You get `NaN` because a computation is undefined.  Looking at your code one of these has to be `NaN`:  `event.wheelDelta`, `event.detail` , or  `(rolled/Math.abs(rolled))/10`

Comment: Oh I guess i found out what is wrong . zoomImage function is not acting like a function of class cause it is a function connected to the event. So event.scale is undefined. or Something wrong with the variable scope i guess..I am confused...How can i fix this ?

Comment: I checked rolled value before and after calculation it always reports negative or positive 120 vinegarbin.

Comment: Is `event` a `MouseWheelEvent` ?

Comment: Right.  So, it is that `this.iscale` is undefined. I think that is what you meant when you said `event.scale` is undefined.  It seems the problem is related to how `contentImage.zoomImage` is being used with your event.  That is beyond the context of what you've shown.

Comment: I edited the post and added that part as well vinegarbin.. yes I mean "this.iscale".

Comment: The only thing I see is that `con` is not being set in `constructor`.